# What does the derived unit "square coulomb" quantify?

Tags: electromagnetism, units, coulombs-law, physical-constants, si-units

As a square meter (m$^2$) quantifies area and not length, what does a square coulomb (C$^2$) quantify?

Comment: Squared distance does not always mean area. For example, the potential energy of a spring is $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$. If the displacement $x$ is in units of m, then $x^2$ is in m$^2$, but that quantity has nothing to do with any particular area.

Comment: A coulomb-squared simply quantifies the product of two charges, or the product of a charge with itself.